# Transfer from HTML to AngularJS?

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to transfer data from HTML to JS, and I'm using `Angular JS`

I can transfer only 1 `param`

**This is my code**

**HTML**

```
<ons-row  class="list-item-container" ng-click="afisha(item.fullopis)">
```

**JS**

```
 $scope.afisha = function(qqrq) {
  $scope.fullopis= qqrq;
  afishamodal.show();
  };
```

But I want transfer 2 and more params.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass n number of parameters:

```
<ons-row  class="list-item-container" ng-click="afisha(item.fullopis,param2,param3,...,paramn)">

$scope.afisha = function(qqrq, param2, param3,... paramn) {
    $scope.fullopis = qqrq;
    afishamodal.show();
};
```

Thanks,

Vishal Patel|simplified-it-outsourcing.com